# Gradle - Dynamically building multiple publishes

Tags: groovy, gradle, ivy

I have come on to a project which has a Gradle script that builds tasks dynamically based on a list. This is so that when people fork the repository, they can just edit the list. It boils down to something like this:

```
def files = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']

files.each { f ->
    task (f, type: Exec) {
        executable 'touch'
        args file
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is to be able to publish the outputs of the tasks. I ideally want to do this as multiple publishes. I gave it a stab with the below code snippet, but Gradle seems to really hate the fact that I'm using a `java.lang.String.call()` as a class name!

```
publishing {
    publications {
        files.each { f ->
            f (IvyPublication) {
                module f
                artifact (file(f))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is what I am trying to do possible, or should I completely change tack?

[edit] I *think* I can do this with `IvyPublication.loadClass(f)`, but struggling with the details. Any help much appreciated

Comment: This hasn't been tested, but it's worth trying `it.f (IvyPublication) {`.  The `it` will refer to the calling class and since file1/file2/etc. methods won't exist the `methodMissing` method within the builder should get executed.

Comment: Nice, that seems to work also. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Aha! I have found the solution. It's not as exciting as using the class loader, but it does work:

```
publishing {
    files.each { f ->
        publications.create(f, IvyPublication) {
            module f
            artifact (file(f))
        }
    }
}
```